# Keyboard shortcut to go back to the Console after hitting a breakpoint

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any keyboard shortcut to go back to the *Console* in the *Console Drawer* after hitting a breakpoint?

[image]

Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> works if the *Console Drawer* is not open yet, but if it is already open, I need to press <kbd>ESC</kbd> twice. Not a big deal, however <kbd>ESC</kbd> does not work if the *Search* tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) is the selected tab in the *Console Drawer*.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the shortcut myself, it is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

Read more at [console panel keyboard shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts#console)